# How to use the x-ms-replica-session-key header?

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

I believe this header can be used to maintain affinity with a specific replica, to get write-then-read consistency in a series of calls to AAD graph.  But I can't find any documentation for it, save for a mention on this page (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-error-codes-and-error-handling) not to use it under certain error conditions.  What is the correct way to use this header?